# Synfusion WinForms GridDataBoundGrid: What events are they for detecting header clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I recently installed syncfusion(Previously using telerik) and am trying to switch out the the `RadGridView` for the `GridDataBoundGrid` and my function doesnt seem to work the same as it did

```c#
private void OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventHandler e) {
            if (e.Row is GridViewTableHeaderRowInfo) {
                int index = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
                EditHeader eh = new EditHeader(this.UpdateHeader);
                eh.TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[index.ToString()].Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ToString();
                eh.TextBox2.Text = e.ColumnIndex.ToString();
                eh.Show();
            }
        }
```

`e.Row` Doesnt exist `GridViewTableHeaderRowInfo` Doesnt exist and `e.ColumnIndex` Doesnt exist

The point of this is to open another part of the application when a column header is clicked and im not sure if im gonna have to rewrite the function from scratch or not.

So are there any events that would work directly with my function or do I have to write a workaround

Answer (score 0):

By default, the **CellClick** event will trigger while the clicking on table cells. The **CellType** property can be used to check whether the CurrentCell is column header cell or not and the **ColIndex** property can be used to get the current column index. Please make use of code and sample,

Code snippet

```
//Event Triggering
this.gridDataBoundGrid1.CellClick += GridDataBoundGrid1_CellClick;

//Event handling
private void GridDataBoundGrid1_CellClick(object sender, GridCellClickEventArgs e)
{
    //To Check for column header cell
    if(this.gridDataBoundGrid1[e.RowIndex, e.ColIndex].CellType == "ColumnHeaderCell")
{
//Your code show the another part of the project.
}
}
```

Note

Please make use of below KB to get the particular record/row based on index.

KB link: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5953/how-to-get-the-row-data-from-griddataboundgrid

Sample link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwk9nUFE3rlxR0xZMXRhU0xqdTA/view?usp=sharing

Regards,

Arulpriya